# How to find the index for jquery accordion panel that given element is in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I am using a jQuery accordion for a multi part registration form, and before submitting the form I need to make sure all required fields are filled in.  So if I find a required field that is not filled in I need to open the accordion panel that it is in so that I can put focus on that field for the user.

I've already got the id of the offending element so I can get a handle to the field like so

```
$('#' + columnname)
```

But I can't figure out how to determine which panel this field is in. 
I tried this:

```
var accordionindex = $('#' + columnname).closest('.ui-accordion-content').index();
```

But this doesn't seem to work because it returns 1 for the first panel, and it returns 3 for the second panel. And if I subtract 1 I end up with 0 for the first panel (which is correct) and 2 for the second panel (which is still incorrect).

I also tried:

```
var accordionindex = $('#' + columnname).closest("H4").index()
```

But this returns a -1 for all panels.

My accordion is initiated like so:

```
$('#registration').accordion({
     collapsible: false,
     header: 'h4',
     heightStyle: 'content',
     active: 0
})
```

Surely there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: Without see the HTML its hard to say. Without an argument it gives index of all siblings. Perhaps you have other elements in there. Maybe pass a selector to index so its only giving the index of a specific element. https://jsfiddle.net/fek54n2t/2/

Comment: Yeh you need to post the markup ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also possible to extract the panel index from the accordion's data:

```
// id is like 'ui-accordion-accordion-panel-2'
var elems = $('#' + columnname).closest('.ui-accordion-content').attr('id').split('-');
var accordionindex = parseInt(elems[elems.length - 1], 10);
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/O9XxyYNWg2Cwy5wBWZXB?p=preview) (check the code in script.js).

Comment: I like this answer because if I ever add another panel I don't have to worry about adding data attributes to it.  It will just work.

Comment: @Vincent you are right about parseInt, I had it in plunker and now also updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6mSA/890/)**.

You can use **[data attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** to store index of every panel in your accordion, then get it when you're trying to active the panel of input, check the example bellow.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
  <div data-index='0'>
    <p>Section 1 Content</p>
  </div>

  <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
  <div data-index='1'>
    <p>Section 2 Content</p>
  </div>

  <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
  <div data-index='2'>
    <p>
       Section 3 Content
      <input id="test" type='text'>
    </p>
  </div>

  <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
  <div data-index='3'>
    <p>Section 4 Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(function() {
      $("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: true, collapsible: true});

      //Get panel index of input `#test` 
      var index = $('#test').closest('.ui-accordion-content').data('index');

      //Active panel of input `#test` 
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", index );
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  Looks like a good solution but I prefer one that doesn't rely on markup, if possible.